# STS Java exit code 13

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, exit-code

I've reviewed previous answers for this type of question, and have tried to act according to the answers given but still come up with this problem.

I've deleted previous versions of Eclipse and installed the 64-bit version in line with my OS, ensured JRE is for 64-bit.

Below, is my STS.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Xverify:none
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx768m
```

And for eclipse:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\KIDS\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Absence of -vm is since I added that before all the re-installing but with the new installations the same problem occurs.

Comment: The STS.ini is for 32 bit

Comment: can't believe I didn't even notice that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STS.ini is for 32 bit – greg-449